# Loading several DropDowns on page load faster

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, asp.net-4.0

I have several DropDown controls on a Web Form which are filled using AJAX call to a method in a class.

I call methods as below:

1. FillDistricts();
2. FillVillages();
3. FillTowns();

I thought these independent calls are creating too many round trips to the server and therefore I altered the class to fill all the DropDowns at once.

I pass the names of all the DropDowns as an array to a class which has a method to populate those DropDowns in a loop.

I want to know whether it will make some difference in page loads.

Comment: What roundtrips are you talking about? Unless you use a webservice and call individual methods from your client, there are no roundtrips to talk about (except for SQL server, but doesn't seem to be the case here)...

Comment: With my present method, I call a method with DropDown name as the parameter. The control goes to the class, populates the parameter and reads the next statement. It again goes to the class to populate another DropDown. Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: Update your question so it clearly says you're using AJAX. It's a completely different question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Page.Cache to store the results in, if that cache doesnt exists load the items, and save them into the cache, and may the same results be queried again, check to see if its already in the cache if so load it from the cache